# Anylogic: How to execute a downtime for only some workers of a same resourcePool

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have to model a task in which in a simplified example two workers do some work on queue of objects they have. but their work shifts may differ and my model should support this.

Is there any way for doing this simply that each unit of a same resource pool has different work schedule?

I tried a self developed solution in which I used two separate resource pools each one has a capacity of one, and assigned both resource pools to the service block. but the problem is that output rate of the new configuration is less than when using a single resource pool of capacity two.

In the system with on resource pool as shown in below image, two workers are working simultaneously on two different parts and after 350 time units 5 agents has passed the service block.

**When using on resource pool with capacity two**
[image]
model when one resource pool is used.

[image]
output in this system

**When using two resource pools with capacity one**
[image]
model when two resource pools are used.

[image]
output in new system

As it is shown in last image after 350 time units 3 agents has passed the service block when two resource pools are used. the other difference is number of parts which are processed simultaneously. when we use one resource pool the number is two and when we use two different resource pools only one part is processed at a time.

Does any one knows why this happens and is there any way for my main question or any solution for my own developed way to make the rate of process equal? a way in which when two resource pools are used the number parts processed simultaneously becomes two like the previous way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ideally edit your question title (given the accepted answer) since this is (now) really nothing to do with executing downtime only for some workers (which, BTW, is not easy and --- at the crudest level --- would be done by splitting into multiple resource pools with different downtime characteristics).

Comment: @StuartRossiter, can you help me on better ways than the so called crudest level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see, in your second model, you are telling the service that you need BOTH resources to work ONE agent... what you should do is click on the "add list" button that you are ignoring, and add both resourcePools as alternatives as you see in the following picture:

[image: service]

By doing this, instead of telling the service to use one unit of each resource pool, you are telling it to use either a unit from resourcePool OR (and this is a very important or) a unit from resourcePool1, in case no resource from resourcePool1 is available

Comment: Note that AnyLogic's inconsistent terminology for this doesn't help. "Add list" is really adding an **alternative resource set**, where each set is a requirement for 1+ resource agents from 1+ pools. It is explained pretty clearly in the help page though: *Library Reference Guides > Process Modeling Library > Using resources*.

Comment: BTW your last paragraph should really talk about `resourcePool` and `resourcePool1`, not `resourcePool1` and `resourcePool2`.