# AnyLogic: Error when different resource pools are used in parallel using Add List Button

Tags: simulation, anylogic

after answers and comments given in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605658/anylogic-how-to-execute-a-downtime-for-only-some-workers-of-a-same-resourcepool), I encountered new error when using such configuration. before depicting the error, it would be valuable that you consider that I have 5 different resource pools and their capacity is either 1 or zero. number of resource pools with capacity one is determined by user when he declares number of total workers working in this section. In other words I have modeled each worker as one resource pool and according to the fact that number of workers is supposed to be variable; I change the capacity of excess resource pools to zero. first of all is it a right approach?

second when I use such configuration,
[image]
(each resource is different and because of their name length last numbers are not visible, i.e. demontage140W1, demontage140W2 and so on)

such an error is encountered:

```
Internal error: there are reserved units in one-by-one request while pool root.demontage140WorkersPool1 is being discarded: Request P-20-P-NP from root.<population>[19] (at root.seize) for resources [null:0, demontage140WorkersPool1:1, demontage140WorkersPool2:0, demontage140WorkersPool3:0, demontage140WorkersPool4:0] with sets [null, [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], null, null, null]
```

Does anyone knows what should be done to solve the problem?

**NEW DATA-EDIT**

[image]

This image shows the condition of two first resource pools when the error has occurred. Any new Idea?

Comment: never saw this, but i can't reproduce your error with the info

Comment: @Felipe , does this image in edit helps you?

Comment: @Bhargav Rao, why did you deleted my answer? what was the problem?

Comment: because your answer was a clarification of your question, not an answer... and even when I saw it, i replicated your exact model and didnt get your error... so you are missing to say something

Comment: @Felipe you mean you didn't get error when using seize policy of one by one? strange!
I solved my error in main model by changing one by one to whole set at once...

Comment: yeah i don't get the error